# Facing error while installing using npm in node js

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js

well I am new to javascript and node js , I have install node js but whenever I am installing seraph, seraph-resource , d3.js using npm

```
npm install seraph
npm install seraph-resource
npm install d3.js
npm install express.js
```

I am facing below error :

[image]

I am facing error in package.json, can anyone please help me solve this error.

Comment: These are warnings not errors. Do `npm init` first.

Comment: I am new to neo4j graph db and installing these js package for graph virtualization does this mean that it may work correctly

Comment: Yes, it will work correctly. The output indicates simply that you don't have the `package.json` file. `package.json` is used to keep track of the dependencies of the project. Though you don't have it, the `modules` you installed will be downloaded. But as @GregHerbowicz mentionned, if you do `npm init` first before installing your modules, it will create the file `package.json` for you.